# How do I animate a flip of a UIView multiple times in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, transition

I would like to flip the image on a `UIButton` multiple times.  i.e. A revolving door type animation. I don't care if it flips a certain number of times or for a duration of time

Right now I can flip it once, using this code:

```
UIView.transition(with: thisButton, duration: 0.2, options: .transitionFlipFromTop, animations: {
    thisButton.setImage(myButtonImage, for: .normal)
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: You can also set repeat count to control it!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `.repeat` to your options

```
UIView.transition(with: thisButton, duration: 0.2, options: [.transitionFlipFromTop,.repeat], animations: {
    thisButton.setImage(myButtonImage, for: .normal)
}, completion: nil)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Reinier's answer works to make it continue repeating forever.

To make it stop after some time I added `thisButton.layer.removeAllAnimations()`

So the following code together works:

```
UIView.transition(with: thisButton, duration: 0.1, options: [.transitionFlipFromTop,.repeat], animations: {
    thisButton.setImage(myButtonImage, for: .normal)
}, completion: nil)

let delayTime = DispatchTime.now() + 0.5
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: delayTime) {
    thisButton.layer.removeAllAnimations()
}
```